# Cannot add new Integration Runtime for Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have owner role in subscription level and I can create new pipeline in Azure Data Factory.
However I don't see "New" button in Integration Runtime.

Is this permission related problem? Which permission is missing then?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/create-self-hosted-integration-runtime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Self-hosted integration runtime is used to connect to your on-premise source/linked server.

When create the dataset, linked server, we can see the "New" button:
[image]

You also could create the integration runtime by this way:
**Manage**-->**Connections**: integration runtimes-->**New**-->**Azure,self-hosted**-->**Self-hosted**:
[image]

Then you could choose the self-hosted integration to connect to your on-premise source.